# (Javascript) Materializecss collapsible instantly open then close when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm trying to create a collapsible using Materializecss 100 and Materialize JS. When creating my collapsible like so and clicking on it, it just open and close immediatly

```
 <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
```

And putting the init on the Document ready like so :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('.collapsible').collapsible({
});
```

});

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not knowing the library this is just an assumption: Do you maybe initialise the accordion twice, i.e. once by data-collapsible and/or the css class and once in JavaScript? Can you remove the JavaScript part and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Collapsible elements only need initialization if they are added dynamically

The accordion is already initialised on document ready.

Removing the following should make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I imported Materialize JS twice, one time in my layout shared with all my pages and one more time in my page itself.